# Word order in subordinate clause

Tags: ordre-des-mots

Is the word order correct here:

> j'espère, que trouve toi bien cette carte ?

Or:

> j'espère que toi cette carte trouve bien ?

Or is neither correct?

I want to say ¨I hope this card finds you well¨

Comment: Welcome. The 2 phrases are actually incorrect. Could you please write in English the idea you wanted to express?

Comment: The title bears almost no relation to the question content. You might want to change it.

Comment: Many thanks.  I want to say ¨I hope this card finds you well¨.

Answer (score 2):

Neither. *Toi* is a [stressed pronoun](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/stressed-pronouns/), so you only use it in certain specific ways, such as after a preposition.

In your sentence, assuming you mean "I hope this card finds you well," you need the [direct object pronoun](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/direct-objects/) *te* and it has to go in front of the verb:

*J'espère que cette carte te trouve bien*.

Comment: *J'espère que cette carte te trouve en bonne santé* ?

Comment: Indeed. “te trouve bien” is not idiomatic, it sounds more like a (wrong) literal translation from English. “te trouve en bonne santé” is understandable but still has some English flavor.

Comment: @GAMPUB I understand neither "te trouve bien" nor "te trouve en bonne santé"... what is the expected meaning ?

Comment: @Random: "I hope this card finds you well." I hope you are well when this card arrives.

Comment: Yes, this phrase clearly does not translate smoothly into French and I should try to find something more idiomatic.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

the word order should be :

```
J'espère que cette carte te trouvera bien.
```

(where "toi" is replaced by "te" and placed between the subject (cette carte) and the verb (trouve) )

However, this type of sentence sentence doesn't sound good in French, I would rather write :

```
J'espère que tu recevras bien cette carte.
```

or

```
J'espère que cette carte te sera bien transmise/remise.
```

if you have some doubt that the message could get lost.

EDIT: if you want to say that you hope that the person reading the letter is in good health, you can simply say :

```
J'espère que tu vas bien (or "que vous allez bien" if this is a formal letter).
```

Comment: This is not the same meaning. This wording is a bit of a personification of the card, _trouver_ has the same meaning as in _Je ne sais pas dans quel état je vais le trouver._

Comment: Many thanks for your help.